# Escaping special characters when using NET USE

Tags: networking, batch-file, automated-tests, credentials, nas

I'd like to at least make a simple /delete of my current credentials to a shared drive work.  https://superuser.com/questions/123833/how-do-i-change-the-user-i-am-logged-in-with-on-a-network-share was helpful in giving examples of how NET USE should work, but perhaps my shared drive's special characters are interfering(?)

```
NET USE "\\example-of.my.domain\and-share$" /delete
```

results in: "The network connection could not be found.  More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250."

The command is actually to be used in a SoapUI script, so Java / Groovy / other commands to accomplish the same task are also welcome responses.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the thing with NET USE is that I was getting a non-specific error that led me to believe the shared drive wasn't found.  In reality, the shared drive name was fine, but I hadn't explicitly connected to this drive I wanted deleted in this same DOS window (I made the assumption NET USE would remove my mapped drive letter, but that's just not the case).  In the end, it's my *assumption* that I can ignore the error if I get it when deleting access to the shared drive, then in a 2nd NET USE command, map to the same drive with specific credentials.  **This is in order to run my test automation scripts on various machines in different environments**.  If anyone knows of a better way to accomplish this, please feel free to contribute here.  Thanks again